# Active sheets based on names in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array of fruit names ("APPLE", "PEAR", "GRAPE", etc.) and each of those sheets contains a graph to obtain the count values in the main sheet.
I would like to activate them one by one to fill in the values in the graph in them.
I tried:

```
        For i = LBound(fruit) To UBound(fruit)
            fruit(i) = Trim(fruit(i))
            Dim country As Variant
            For Each fru In fruit
             If fruit <> "" Then
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(fruit)
                    slrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).row
                    For j = 2 To slrow     
                            Cells(j, 4).Value = 0
                            Cells(j, 5).Value = 0
                            Cells(j, 6).Value = 0
                            Exit For 
                    Next j
                 End With
             End If
            Next fruit
        Next i
```

But seems the sheet has not been activating at all.

Comment: When you have `For Each fru In fruit` then you need to continue with `If fru = "" Then`. But why are you looping the same array twice `For i = LBound(fruit) To UBound(fruit)`?

Comment: Also you need to fully qualify the cells object otherwise they will refer to the active worksheet.. Add a DOT before the Cells Object. For example `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).row` or `.Cells(j, 4).Value = 0` and so on...

Comment: Hello the code doesn’t work every after I adding Dot

Comment: a) The way you describe your problem does not help to understand it. You write: I have a table with fruit names ("APPLE", "PEAR", "GRAPE", etc.) and each of these sheets... Do you mean that you have a table with sheet names?
b) Is your code in another sheet's module or is it in a module inside the modules folder?
c) Υou want to fill an area on each sheet with values, from which area of which sheet will you get the values and to which area will you copy them?
From what little I know I'm sure if you describe your problem in detail it's easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you loop through the fruits array twice? You have the outer loop with ubound and lbound and then the inner for each loop. Wouldn't one be enough? You also have "for each fru" but then you have "next fruit". This makes no sense. Also what is the "country" variable declaration for? It isn't used anywhere.

To avoid mistakes like this, I would recommend using "option explicit" at the top of your module. This will force you to declare all variables. Any undeclared variable will throw an error.

I attempted to fix the code like so:

```vb
Dim fr As String
For i = LBound(fruit) To UBound(fruit)
    fruit(i) = Trim(fruit(i))
    fr = fruit(i)
    If fr <> "" Then
        On Error GoTo errorHandling
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(fr)
            slrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
            For j = 2 To slrow
                .Cells(j, 4).Value = 0
                .Cells(j, 5).Value = 0
                .Cells(j, 6).Value = 0
                Exit For
            Next j
        End With
    End If
Next i

'put the following 3 lines at the end of your sub or just leave them here if your code ends here
Exit Sub
errorHandling:
MsgBox "Sheet " & fr & " does not exist"
```